# Iteration over file - check if the string from other file is present in the line of source file

Tags: python

I have a source file that looks like this:

```
1   AX-75454925 0   563128
1   AX-75469048 0   573126
1   AX-75492867 0   584209
1   AX-75534944 0   605258
1   AX-75563461 0   619069
...
```

I also have a file with the list of ID's that looks like this:

```
AX-80968854
AX-75258857
AX-75259850
AX-75259941
AX-75260842
...
```

> **I want to delete lines in a source file in a way that only the lines that include the strings from the ID list are left.**

I've tried to solve the problem using Python - but was only able to write the solution that checks if lines are the same in both files (not **only the string**, like *AX-75454925*).

Here's what I've tried:

```
outfile = open("output.txt", "a")

def checkLine(ID):        
    with open("source.map") as f:
        for line in f:
            if ID in line:
                outfile.write(line)

for ID in open("IDs.txt", "r"):
    checkLine(ID)
```

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Each Stack Overflow question should be about a _specific technical problem_. Not having picked an implementation language is the very opposite of specific. Each language should have its own question -- it's fine to ask two different questions of two different communities, because you're hitting different implementation problems with each attempt!

Comment: As for the `comm` side, there are two problems: (1) You need to have both inputs sorted the same way; (2) you need to extract only the column you want from `source.map`. If you want _all_ the columns in your output, you should use `join`, not `comm`.

Comment: **Your sample IDs don't match up!** Therefore, correct output from your sample data is an empty file. That's not a very good choice of examples.

Comment: Sorry for the mess up on my part - this is my first post on StackOverflow. Thanks for the tips though - will follow them going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is definitely the easier language to do this in. You're going to want to read the whole set of search terms from the one file in, and then check each line against the whole set:

```py
# read IDs file
with open('IDs.txt') as ids_file:
    ids = {id.strip() for id in ids_file}
# make sure we don't have any empty IDs
ids = set(filter(None, ids))

# open the files
with open('extra_lines.txt') as in_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file
        for line in in_file:
            # check if any IDs are in the line
            if any(id in line for id in ids):
                out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Note that you can put both the `open`s on one `with` statement / in a single line.